# Give a grammar for a language on Σ={a,b,c} that accepts all strings containing exactly one a

Tags: regular-languages, formal-grammars

I have created the following solution but its left recursive:
S--> a|bSc|cSb|Sbc
Also it is not accepting:
"ab" or "cba" or "abb" or abc.

Somebody please guide me.

Zulfi.

Comment: There's no requirement that there needs to be an equal number of `b`s and `c`s, which your grammar tries to satisfy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$S\rightarrow aA, bS,cS$$

$$A\rightarrow bA, cA, \epsilon$$

Note that you need at least two non-terminals for this language, since you need to differentiate two states, namely whether an $a$ has already been added/found or not.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to arrive at a solution here - you might recognize that this language is regular, since, intuitively, you’d only need to remember whether you’d seen zero a’s, one a, or two or more a’s.

You can build a very simple two-state NFA for this regular language. The start state corresponds to having seen no a’s. It isn’t accepting and has a self-loop on b and c and a transition to a second state on a. That state corresponds to having seen one a, has self-loops on b and c, and dies off on seeing another a. *(Note: I lack the LaTeXpertise to actually draw this automaton out. Please edit this answer if you know how to do that!)*

Once you have this NFA, you can convert it into a CFG (more specifically, a right-linear grammar) as follows:

- Create one nonterminal for each state.
- For each transition from a state $Q$ to a state $R$ on character $x$, add the production rule $Q \to xR$.
- For each accepting state $Q$, add a production $Q \to \varepsilon$.

This construction produces a CFG with the same language as the NFA - do you see why? And, in a cool twist, it produces the exact grammar given by @narekBoljikian in their answer! So you can think of that approach as what you’d get if you built an NFA and then turned it into a CFG.

Hope this helps!