# How can I convert from DFA in to regular grammar?

Tags: automata, finite-automata, formal-grammars, regular-expressions

I have following information.

```
        0    1
-> *q0  q0  q1
    q1  q1  q2
    q2  q2  q0
```

I have to convert this in to a regular grammar.

I wrote this:

```
q0 = q2,0 + ε
q1 = q0,0 + q1,0
q2 = q2,0 + q1,1 + q1,1
```

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/117866/4416

Comment: http://www.cs.nuim.ie/~jpower/Courses/Previous/parsing/node17.html

Comment: I count five errors in your proposed grammar. Can you point us to a source which guided you to the method of conversion or did you just try to figure it out? Help us to help you.

Comment: I just try it. I don´t know how I can solve this.

Answer (score -2):

Treat the DFA like a PDA, and then use [some algorithm that transforms PDAs to CFGs.](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/automata_theory/pda_context_free_grammar.htm)

Comment: Is PDA the same es DFA ?

Comment: No, a PDA is a stronger version of a DFA. Basically, its a DFA with an additional stack. Hence every DFA is also a PDA (but not vice versa)